# Python, best way to write a sum of two for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, coding-style

Normally I know we can do `sum([func(x,x) for x in i])`, but I got an if check and two for loops, so what is the most pythonic way to write the code bellow. you can assume that similarity will return a number regardless of what type you give it. You can also assume that it will really only get ints and chars.

```
x = 0
if isinstance(a, dict) or isinstance(a, list) or isinstance(a, tuple):
    for i in a:
        for j in b:
            x += similarity (i,j)
```

Comment: The `if` isn't inside any loop, so… why does it need to be inside the `sum`?

Comment: For your example, instead of the list comprehension of `sum([func(x,y) for x in i])` you can use `sum(func(x,y) for x in i)` as a generator and not generate the intermediate list

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
x=0
if isinstance(a,(dict,list,tuple)):
    x=sum(similarity(i,j) for i in a for j in b)
```

Or:

```
x=(sum(similarity(i,j) for i in a for j in b) if isinstance(a,(dict,list,tuple)) 
   else 0)
```

Or (assuming that a string, set or some other iterable type does not break your function for some reason):

```
try:
   x=sum(similarity(i,j) for i in a for j in b)
except TypeError:
   x=0
```

---

If you are specifically looking to test if something is iterable, you can do that this way:

```
from collections import Iterable
if isinstance(e, Iterable):
   ...
```

If there are certain iterable types you do not want, react to those:

```
if isinstance(e, Iterable) and not isinstance(el, str):
   # an iterable that is not a string...
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `any` with `isinstance`, when you can just pass all the types to `isinstance` itself.

Comment: It looks like someone downvoted _all_ of the first 4 answers posted, with no explanation for any of them. Annoying, but… what are you going to do?

Comment: Let's push us up for the comments to compensate ;-)

Comment: The `try`/`except` variant has the problem that it silently swallows any `TypeError` raised inside `similarity` (and also inside `sum`), which is almost certainly not desired. As Guido once noted of Google's Python code, one of the most common mistakes are `try` clauses that encompass way too much code.

Comment: So is there a better catch, or a better way to catch in this case?

Comment: @EasilyBaffled: I agree with user4815162342, the `try/except` structure should only be used if you know that `similarity` is unlikely to generate a `TypeError` that is unrelated to setting `x=0`

Answer (score 9):

You probably want something like:

```
if isinstance(a, (dict, list, tuple)):
    x = sum(similarity(i, j) for i in a for j in b)
else:
    x = 0
```

Comment: Why was this one downvoted? True, it doesn't add anything that wasn't already in at least 2 pre-existing answers, but since when is that a reason to downvote?

Comment: No idea about the downvote, but to "defend" the answer: when it was written, no other answer passed a tuple to `isinstance`, nor did any show that `sum` defaults to 0, which makes an unconditional assignment unnecessary. In addition, some of the existing answers were unnecessarily wordy.

Comment: Given the choice of explaining changes the OP is unlikely to understand, vs. giving him some code that apparently does what he wants by magic so he can cargo-cult his way to code he can't maintain or even debug, I don't think the former is "too wordy". (Also, my answer was the first one. And, while it didn't _show_ using `isinstance` with a tuple, it had the same information: "Meanwhile, `isinstance` can take a `tuple` of types to check for…" I didn't show it because I thought it was better to show that he didn't need type-checking at all.)

Comment: @abarnert I wasn't referring to your answer specifically. I have no idea why you claim that my answer invites cargo-cult imitation. The only part that could be considered cryptic when presented to a Python beginner, the nested comprehension, is present in all code variants in your answer as well.

Comment: You're assuming that explaining things the OP apparently didn't know how to do is "unnecessarily wordy".

Comment: Well, yes, except "unnecessarily wordy" is not an assumption, but a statement of taste. When there's one obvious way to write a piece of code (and that way is simple enough not to require explanation), I prefer to just present it as-is and leave it to the poster to figure it out. My answer reflects my taste and your answer reflects yours, which is how it should be.

Answer (score 7):

You could use some functions from `itertools`, perhaps:

```
from itertools import starmap, product
x = sum(starmap(similarity, product(a, b)))
```

and as others noted, may as well pass a tuple of types to `isinstance()` if you really need to check.

Answer (score 5):

Since the `if` isn't inside a loop, it doesn't need to be inside the list comprehension when you convert it:

```
x = 0
if isinstance(a, dict) or isinstance(a, list) or isinstance(a, tuple):
    x = sum([similarity(i, j) for i in a for j in b])
```

Meanwhile, you really don't need a list comprehension here, a generator expression will have the same effect without having to build a list:

```
x = 0
if isinstance(a, dict) or isinstance(a, list) or isinstance(a, tuple):
    x = sum(similarity(i, j) for i in a for j in b)
```

---

Meanwhile, `isinstance` can take a `tuple` of types to check for, so:

```
x = 0
if isinstance(a, (dict, list, tuple)):
    x = sum(similarity(i, j) for i in a for j in b)
```

… but really, I don't think you want to check in the first place. As long as `a` is any iterable, the code will work, so… why should I force it to be those specific types? If you don't want an exception, just handle the exception:

```
try:
    x = sum(similarity(i, j) for i in a for j in b))
except TypeError:
    x = 0
```

Comment: @DSM: Yes, my answer already says that. But really, he shouldn't be using it at all, as I explained in the edit. (At any rate, it isn't relevant to the main question he was asking.)

Comment: The first version had the sentence "Meanwhile, `isinstance` can take a `tuple` of types to check for, but really, why do you need to check at all?" I expanded on the first part in the first edit, and on the second in the second edit.

Comment: @abarnert: it's entirely likely that I missed it, then, if it was only mentioned in v1 in the last sentence.  I'm actually a little surprised that someone would want to sum over a dict as well as a list and tuple, but I guess there's no accounting for taste.

Comment: @DSM: My fault for continually rewriting answers in the first few minutes. I think "Yeah, that's good enough", then look at it and say, "Wait, the OP might not get what I mean there…", and then, "That part is a bit misleading," and…

Answer (score 1):

In one line ; )

```
x = sum(similarity(i, j) for i in a for j in b) if isinstance(a, (dict, list, tuple)) else 0
```

Comment: That's true, but variety is nice, and my is there some variety in these answers. I'm learning lot about python, whether it looks nice or not

Answer (score 0):

```
if type(a) in [dict, list, tuple]:
    x += sum(similarity(i, j) for i in a for j in b)
```

yeah, type is not the same as isistance but it isn't a dramatic issue..

if the OP wanted to use that piece of code with anything resembling dict, list or tuples (so with subclasses and all) it should really just check that the a is iterable.

something like:

```
def isiterable(obj):
    try:
        iter(obj)
        return True
    except TypeError:
        return False

if isiterable(a):
    x += sum(similarity(i, j) for i in a for j in b)
```

Comment: using `type` is not the same as `isinstance`, and not a good idea

Comment: Ok dumb question, why not?

Comment: @EasilyBaffled: What if I pass in something that's an instance of a subclass of `dict`? That will work with `isinstance`, but it will not work with explicitly checking `type`.

Comment: @Ant: And that's exactly why it _is_ a dramatic issue. Using `isinstance` is already bad enough, because you're using OO when duck typing is fine. But switching on `type` makes it a lot worse, because you're _breaking_ OO.

Comment: @Ant: You're still missing the point. The OP was handling subclasses, and your version does not. And what do you gain along with that cost? Meanwhile, your "check for iterable" has the nice side effect of creating an iterator out of it, which isn't actually guaranteed to be side-effect free. If you want to work with any iterable, just EAFTP it.